# How can I convert a python program into a web service?

Tags: php, python, django, web-services

I have a python program. It takes some text from a text file (A) as an input, do some text annotation and stores the annotated text as an output in another file (B). Now, my plan was to make this like a web service.

I could do this using php and calling the python program from php. Specifically, my php code does this-

--Takes text from a HTML textarea.

--Saves the text into file A.

--Runs the python program.

--Load the output from file B and show the annotated text in the HTML textarea.

Now, to do the text annotation, python program needs to load a model from another big file (C). I would say, loading time is 10 sec and annotating takes 2 sec. Each time, I have a new text in the HTML textarea, I need 12 sec to show the output. I want to minimize the overall time.

I was thinking, if I could communicate from PHP with an already running python program, I could actually save 10 sec. Because, then python would just need to load the model file C once and it could apply the model on any text that PHP sends him and it could send the output to PHP too.

Is there a way I can achieve this? Can django help here in anyway?

Thank you for reading so much.

Comment: Do you really need to mix PHP and python for this? Why not use just one or the other. How big are the files you are processing. Unless they are very large 10 seconds seems very excessive.

Comment: I can not only use PHP. Because, I need to use python packages to process the input and apply the model over it. I can not only use python. Because, I need other web functions. For example, user registration, and stuff.

Comment: Then why not use python for everything else?

Answer (score 1):

Python can simply do all the tasks without PHP

You can simply write a web service using [HTTP Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) on your own machine like

> http://localhost:your_port/your_service?your_para=???

Except [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/), there are many lightweight web framework to do the task, which are easier for beginners. You can check out the flowing frameworks and choice one you prefer

- [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/)
- [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)
- [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try and definitely get back.

Answer (score 0):

You could use raw sockets in your Python and php programs to make them communicate through TCP locally. 
Make your Python program a TCP server with address 'localhost' and port number, for example, 5555, and then, in your php script, also using sockets, create a client code that sends the to be processed text as a TCP request to your Python script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try and definitely get back.